# PowerShell batch rename with regex?

Tags: powershell

So I have a group of files with the following file names:

a-2.txt
b-1.txt
c-3.txt

I am trying to rename them to something like:

1.txt  ----->b-1.txt

2.txt  ----->a-2.txt

3.txt  ----->c-3.txt

But, I can't figure out what the corresponding regular expression would be, and how to code it into PowerShell. I see tons of examples to remove spaces or underscores, but nothing to remove from a string.

Comment: Why use regex when you can use a counter?  Have a `ForEach` loop with `$counter` set to 1 to start, and `$counter ++` in each loop, with `Rename-Item $file $counter`

Comment: i want to change a-2.txt to 2.txt

Comment: not a-2.txt to 1.txt

Comment: and what regex did you try?

Comment: i dont know i want a regex to remove the string before "-"

Comment: ['.*-'](https://regex101.com/r/FZIOTe/1)

Comment: not even 2 minutes of regex research. truly loving such questions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this (remove whatif)

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -Filter "*.txt" | where BaseName -Match ".-." | %{
$newname="{0}{1}" -f ($_.BaseName -split '-')[1], $_.Extension
Rename-Item $_.FullName $newname -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: didn't changed ?

Comment: i didn't asked that for renaming files
i don't even have files like that to rename

Comment: i just wanted a example code for that so that i could break that code into pieces and learn every piece i could till i got the whole code

Comment: Dbl I totally do not care about this kind of comment, go carry your grievances elsewhere ...